# Checkboxes not submitting after being changed with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with a bunch of checkboxes and input fields.  I'm using jquery(1.10.1) to manipulate a number of things about the form based on user input from another form on the page.  This was all working a few weeks ago but suddenly I've found that none of the checkboxes are submitting after they are changed by jquery.

The checkboxes are of the form:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="prod_70" name="prod[70]" class="product style_1 color_1 lens_3 status_1 " value="1" checked />
```

My Jquery code looks the other form to decide which boxes the user is interested in and then creates a selector based on that and the classes assigned to the checkboxes checking the boxes requested by the user:

```
$(curSel).prop('checked',true);
```

I was using:

```
$(curSel).attr('checked','checked').prop('checked',true);
```

But simplified since that shouldn't be necessary.  I also tried adding a .change() for good measure but that didn't solve the problem so I took it back out.

When I submit the form none of the checked checkboxes show up and $_POST['prod'] (PHP on the backend) isn't there.  $_REQUEST['prod'] is also not there.  The other fields on the form are submitting.  And if I submit the form without letting jquery update anything then the checkboxes do submit and $_POST['prod'] is as expected.

I've used the console in chrome and firebug in firefox to inspect the checkboxes while interacting with the page and 'checked' is being added and removed and the checkboxes are displaying correctly even when they're not submitting.

I've checked the HTML on the page to make sure everything is valid and there aren't any missing close tags or nested tags and the only other JS on the page are for FB's like button and twitters follow button.

I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this and my searches aren't turning up anything similar anymore.

EDITING TO ADD MORE:

After more debugging it appears that the problem isn't with changing the checkboxes.  It's happening when the `<li>` that the checkboxes are in is hidden with  .hide() and then reshown with .show().  After doing that the checkboxes in the `<li>` are never submitting even though other form elements inside the `<li>` are.  Here's a full `<li>`:

```
<li class="prod style_1 color_1 lens_7 status_1  bulk-list-item" id="prod_55">
    <div class="bulk-prod-name">
        <input type="checkbox" id="prod_55" name="prod[55]" class="product style_1 color_1 lens_7 status_1 " value="1" />
        <label for="prod_55">
            <span class="style-name">Player</span>
            <span class="color-name">Matte Black</span> |
            <span class="lens-name">Rose Hi-Def LTD 17/35</span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="part-number">PLMBHD03</span>
            <div style="margin-top:10px;">
                <span class="bulk-prod-status">Status: <b>In Stock</b></span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="bulk-prod-image">
        <div style="position:absolute; top:0;"><img style="width:100%;" src="/art/products/11/1/frame/thumb/1.png"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute; top:0;"><img style="width:100%;" src="/art/products/11/1/lens/thumb/7.png"></div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bulk-prod-price">
        MSRP: $ <input type="text" id="prod_msrp_55" name="prod_msrp[55]" class="msrp inputbox" value="179.00" prod_id="55">
        <input type="hidden" id="prod_msrp_orig_55" class="orig_price" value="179.00" orig_id="prod_msrp_55">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Dealer Price: $ <input type="text" id="prod_dprice_55" name="prod_dprice[55]" class="dprice inputbox" value="90.00" prod_id="55">
        <input type="hidden" id="prod_dprice_orig_55" class="orig_price" value="90.00" orig_id="prod_dprice_55">
    </div>
    <div class="bulk-prod-edit">
        <a href="/admin/add_product.html?product[prod_id]=55&product[is_edit]=1">Edit</a> this product.
        <div style="display:none" id="files_55">
            <table width=100%>
                <tr>
                    <td width=50% valign=top><small>Fullsize:<br>
                        <span style="color:#009900"> /art/products/11/1/frame/full/1.png</span><br>
                        <span style="color:#009900"> /art/products/11/1/lens/full/7.png</span><br>
                        </small>
                    </td>
                    <td width=50% valign=top><small>Thumbnais:<br>
                        <span style="color:#009900"> /art/products/11/1/frame/thumb/1.png</span><br>
                        <span style="color:#009900"> /art/products/11/1/lens/thumb/7.png</span><br>
                        </small>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

And here's the full jQuery that's hiding/showing/checking/unchecking things:

```
    $(document).on('change', '.prod_selector', function(e) {
//      console.log('Selection changed:');
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.prod').hide();
        $('.product').prop('checked', false);
        var lens = $('#lens_selector').val();
        var color = $('#color_selector').val();
        var style = $('#style_selector').val();
        var pstatus = $('#status_selector').val();
        var curSel = '';

        if (lens>0) {
            curSel += '.lens_' + lens;
        }
        if (color>0) {
            curSel += '.color_' + color;
        }
        if (style>0) {
            curSel += '.style_' + style;
        }
        if (pstatus>0) {
            curSel += '.status_' + pstatus;
        }


        if ((lens==0) && (color==0) && (style==0) && (pstatus==0)) {
            curSel = '.prod';
            $('.product').prop('checked',true);
        }

//      console.log('curSel: ' + curSel);
        $(curSel).show()
        $(curSel).prop('checked',true);
        $('#prod_count').text($('.prod:visible').length);
    });
```

After messing with things I've determined that if I don't .hide() anything then it all work as expected (other than not hiding things that need to be hidden) but if any `<li>`'s are hidden then even once their shown again checkboxes inside of them don't get included in the form submission even though other input fields do.

Comment: Check your version control log to see what change you made when it stopped working.

Comment: Are you sure the checkboxes are inside the form?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029870/jquery-serialize-does-not-register-checkboxes

Comment: curSel is the "Current Selector" built based on the users input in the other form on the page.  The checkboxes are changing but even if they're checked (either by jquery or manually) they aren't submitting after jquery touches them.

Comment: No changes were made to the page between when it was working and when it stopped working.  Which is what has me scratching my head the most.  jquery is being loaded from googles CDN so I can't guarantee nothing there changed but it shouldn't have.  And yes I've double (and triple) checked that the checkboxes are in the form - and they do submit if I submit the page without triggering any of the jquery changes.

Comment: Jay Blanchard - I'm not interested in unchecked boxes.  The problem is after jquery unchecks or checks any checkboxes no checkboxes are submitting even those that are checked whether they were checked with .prop('checked',true) or manually by the user.  I'll also clarify that the form is just being submitted normally through the browser not with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I see a semi-colon missing:

```
$(curSel).show()
$(curSel).prop('checked',true);
```

The missing semicolon can stop the second statement from setting any checkbox as checked.

Comment: Good catch!  Can't believe I missed that after staring at this so long.  But it wasn't causing the problem.  I just solved the problem and posted the answer which it turns out was not at all what I initially thought it was.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  Turns out I was asking the wrong question.  After more testing I finally determined that it wasn't jquery causing the problem after all.

The problem was more items were added to the database that this page manages which added more fields to the form and we were hitting the [max_input_vars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) limit in the php config.  Which I realized could be causing the issue after finding this: [Limit of POST arguments in html or php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341149/limit-of-post-arguments-in-html-or-php)

I raised the max_input_vars for this site and now the form is working again.