# Symfony 2: form submission fails on large form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a Symfony 2 `form` component. It works perfectly on small dataset. However, when I try to manage a large dataset (about 800 variables), the form component has a strange behaviour.

Using breakpoint, I've isolated the problem: the `submitted` variable of the `form` is set to `false`. In consequence, the code which persists data is not executed and I'm redirected to the form input page (like the first time).

For some reasons, form variables are not binded to the form object. I "manually" add them as post parameter. As I said before, it works great on smaller dataset.

Any help/suggestion on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: How are you running your installation ? php built in server, nginx, apache, ... ?

Comment: More than likely the request is timing out try setting a higher timeout. That or the post request is exceeding size limits again this can be increased by changing your .ini settings.

Comment: I'm running classic php configuration using MAMP on Windows

Comment: @Doug Size limit is set to 200M (`upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`). I'm not sure about timeout, but all keys with timeout tag have at least 60 secondes ; page is reloaded way before that.

Comment: If you check the raw posted data, can you see all the data (including the form token) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solve by increasing `max_input_vars` (in `php.ini` file) as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341149/limit-of-post-arguments-in-html-or-php).